# Требуется ли тире после слова "бонус"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

**— Холод, волки и в бонус — сдохший автомобиль, — произнес он дрожащим голосом и  нервно ударил рукой о капот машины.**

Нужна ли постановка тире в данном предложении после слова "бонус"?

Comment: Если прямая речь начинается с абзаца, то перед ее началом ставится тире. http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/164-znapr

Answer (score 2):

*Холод, волки **и в бонус — сдохший автомобиль,** — произнес он дрожащим голосом и нервно ударил рукой о капот машины.*

Тире ставится, пауза делается.

Здесь имеет место **инверсия**: *Холод, волки и **сдохший автомобиль в бонус.***

В этом случае пауза и тире нужны для того, чтобы понять грамматику предложения.

**Это однородный ряд назывных предложений**, при этом существительное ***автомобиль*** имеет несогласованное обстоятельственное определение: ***автомобиль в бонус***.